# Как сделать кнопку с прерывистыми рамками?

Tags: html, css, css3

Как сделать кнопку с прерывистыми рамками?

Боковые рамки прерываются на углах как на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пришло на ум вот это.

```css
a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.in {
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="in">
    Привет
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: нормальное решение, только не пойму почему `тег <a>`?

Comment: да можно и button, но визуальные кнопки часто и блочными ссылками делают вроде, я не фронтендер, просто мимо шел)

Comment: .............))))))  Уважаю людей, которые не проходят мимо молча, видя чужую беду...

Answer (score 1):

```css
.button-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
button:before,
button:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
button:after{
  top: auto;
  bottom: 1px;
}
button{
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='button-wrapper'>
  <button>Press</button>
</div>
```